# what is meaning of string inside array python

Tags: python, tkinter

What does "CmdBtn['menu'] = CmdBtn.menu" in second last line mean.

```
def makeCommandMenu():
    CmdBtn = Menubutton(mBar, text='Button Commands', underline=0)
    CmdBtn.pack(side=LEFT, padx="2m")
    CmdBtn.menu = Menu(CmdBtn)
    ...
    ...
    CmdBtn['menu'] = CmdBtn.menu
    return CmdBtn
```

Comment: It means [`CmdButton.__setitem__('menu', CmdBtn.menu)`](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Misc-class.html#__setitem__), which apparently is setting a resource value for the given key.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is probably getting massively downvoted for two reasons: 1. it provides no context for your question, and 2. it is asking about a very very basic part of python (the meaning of the brackets `[]` operator), which means you have either not bothered to read a tutorial OR you are asking what the specific meaning of the `'menu'` key is for the `MenuButton` object. If that last is the case, you need to be more explicit in your question (see point #1). If it is the first, again it would help to be more explicit about what exactly what it is you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `x[y] = z`, it calls the `__setitem__` method.

i.e.

```
x.__setitem__(y, z)
```

In your case, `CmdBtn['menu'] = CmdBtn.menu` means

```
CmdBtn.__setitem__('menu', CmdBtn.menu)
```

The `Menubutton` class does indeed provide a [`__setitem__` method](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Misc-class.html#__setitem__). It looks like this is used to set a "resource value" (in this case `CmdBtn.menu`) for the given key (`'menu'`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "string inside an array".

The brackets operator is used for item access in some kind of sequence (usually a `list`, or a `tuple`), mapping (usually a `dict`, or dictionary), or some other kind of special object (such as this `MenuButton` object, which is not a sequence or a mapping). Unlike in some other languages, in python, ANY object is allowed to make use of this operator.

A `list` is similar to an "array" in other languages. It can contain a mixture of objects of any kind, and it maintains the order of the objects. A `list` object is very useful for when you want to maintain an ordered sequence of objects. You can access an object in a `list` using its index, like this (indexes start at zero):

```
x = [1,2,3] # this is a list
assert x[0] == 1 # access the first item in the list
x = list(range(1,4)) # another way to make the same list
```

A `dict` (dictionary) is useful for when you want to associate values with keys so you can look up the values later using the keys. Like this:

```
d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3) # this is a dict
assert x['a'] == 1 # access the dict
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3} # another way to make the same dict
```

Finally, you may also encounter custom made objects that also use the same item-access interface. In the `Menubutton` case, `['menu']` simply accesses some item (defined by the tkinter API) that responds to the key, `'menu'`. You can make your own object type with item-access, too (python 3 code below):

```
class MyObject:
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return "Here I am!"
```

This object doesn't do much except return the same string for key or index value you give it:

```
obj = MyObject()
print(obj [100]) # Here I am!
print(obj [101]) # Here I am!
print(obj ['Anything']) # Here I am!
print(obj ['foo bar baz']) # Here I am!
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Python [everything is an object](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html) and square brackets means that this object is *subscriptable* (for e.g. `tuple`, `list`, `dict`, `string` and many more). Subscriptable means that this object at least implements the `__getitem__()` method  (and `__setitem__()` in your case).

With those methods it's easy to interact with class members, so don't afraid to build your own example, to understand someone else's code.

Try this snippet:

```
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self):
        #   just two simple members
        self.foo = 'foo'
        self.bar = 'bar'

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        #   example getitem function
        return self.__dict__[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        #   example setitem function
        self.__dict__[key] = value

#   create an instance of FooBar
fb = FooBar()

#   lets print members of instance
#   also try to comment out get and set functions to see the difference
print(fb['foo'], fb['bar'])

#   lets try to change member via __setitem__
fb['foo'] = 'baz'

#   lets print members of instance again to see the difference
print(fb['foo'], fb['bar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is shorthand for `CmdBtn.configure(menu=CmdBtn.menu)`

The way to set widget options is typically at creation time (eg: `Menubutton(..., menu=...)`) or using the `configure` method (eg: `CmdBtn.configure(menu=...)`. Tkinter provides a third method, which is to treat the widget like a dictionary where the configuration values are keys to the dictionary (eg: `CMdBtn['menu']=...`)

This is covered in the [Setting Options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#setting-options) section of the official python tkinter documentation